# 80's/90's Sci-Fi Movie: People on desert planet with robot who jumps through glass at the end?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie when I was a kid in the early 90's. I have no idea what the plot was, but it took place on a desert planet, I believe it involved some sort of farming, and there was a robot they either befriended or were chasing. The robot, from what I remember, looked similar to the Alpha robot from power rangers.

The only scene that sticks out in my mind is towards the end of the movie the robot is jumping and crashing through what look like glass mirrors, why I have no idea.

The glass jumping scene haunts me.

*I'm fairly certain its not Solarbabies*